# How do I aggregate on more than one column within a PIVOT

Tags: sql-server

I have two Column Users and NewUsers I need to sum those two as Quarterly so I am using pivot function so I have written query below....
code is

```
select [week],[years],pivoting.[1] as Q1 ,pivoting.[2] AS Q2,pivoting.[3] AS Q3,pivoting.[4] AS Q4,pivoting.[1] as N1,pivoting.[2] AS N2,pivoting.[3] AS N3,pivoting.[4] AS N4 into #addpivot from 
(
    select Week,years,Quarter,users,NewUsers from #pivottable
) as PivotData 
pivot 
(
     sum(users) for Quarter in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) as pivoting
pivot
(
    sum(NewUsers) for Quarter in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) as pivoting
```

but it showing error in second line **Quarter** invalid column name

Where I am going wrong not able understand please help me.......

Comment: Alternative solution. Use `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 1 THEN users ELSE 0 END) AS Q1` ...

Comment: That would be better @adrianm...

Comment: @adrianm If u dont mind please will explain where should i use I am little bit confusing........

Answer (score 0):

I dint understand what do you mean by multiple values ...
Pivot is as simple as this ...

```
SELECT *
FROM table
PIVOT( SUM(NewUsers) FOR Quarter IN ([1],[2],[3],[4]) ) AS PVTTable
```

Comment: This might help ... http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your data correctly, you need to unpivot your data and add a column to identify the values to pivot on before pivoting. I've called this 'Category' and used CROSS APPLY but you can also use CASE.

```
SELECT * INTO #PivotTable FROM (
VALUES 
(1, 1, 1, 10, 12),
(1, 1, 1, 11, 13),
(1, 1, 2, 8,  10),
(1, 1, 2, 7,  11),
(1, 1, 3, 11, 14),
(1, 1, 3, 8,  15),
(1, 1, 4, 15, 10),
(1, 1, 4, 17, 11)
)A (Week,Years,Quarter,Users,NewUsers)


SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT Week
        ,Years
        ,Category
        ,Value FROM #PivotTable 
        CROSS APPLY 
            (SELECT 'NewUsersQ'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(1),Quarter) Category, NewUsers Value
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'UsersQ'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(1),Quarter) Category, Users Value   
            ) A 
    ) SRC
PIVOT (
        SUM(Value) FOR Category IN 
        ([UsersQ1], [NewUsersQ1], [UsersQ2], [NewUsersQ2], [UsersQ3], [NewUsersQ3], [UsersQ4], [NewUsersQ4]) 
)Pvt

Week        Years       UsersQ1     NewUsersQ1  UsersQ2     NewUsersQ2  UsersQ3     NewUsersQ3  UsersQ4     NewUsersQ4
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           21          25          15          21          19          29          32          21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [week]
      ,[years]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 1 THEN users ELSE 0 END) AS Q1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 2 THEN users ELSE 0 END) AS Q2
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 3 THEN users ELSE 0 END) AS Q3
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 4 THEN users ELSE 0 END) AS Q4
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 1 THEN NewUsers ELSE 0 END) AS N1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 2 THEN NewUsers ELSE 0 END) AS N2
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 3 THEN NewUsers ELSE 0 END) AS N3
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 4 THEN NewUsers ELSE 0 END) AS N4
FROM #pivottable
GROUP BY [week]
        ,[years]
```